# How to properly implement move semantics in a template class?

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
class NP {
public:
    NP() = default;

    NP(T val_1, T val_2) {
        x = val_1;
        y = val_2;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    NP(const NP& abc) {
        x = abc.x;
        y = abc.y;
    }

    // Move constructor
    NP(NP&& other) :
        x(other.x),
        y(other.y)
    {
        other.x = nullptr;
        other.y = nullptr;
    }

    // Move operator
    NP& operator=(const NP&& other) {
        delete x;
        delete y;
  
        x = other.x;
        y = other.y;

        other.x = nullptr;
        other.y = nullptr;
    }

    void GetResult() {
        cout << x << " " << y;
    }
private:
    T x, y;
};

int main()
{
    NP<int> test(0, 0);
    NP<int> test_1(5, 5);

    test = test_1;

    test.GetResult();
}
```

> I have a template class NP that contains two numbers. How to properly
> organize move constructor and move operator in this class? In the move semantics examples, I mostly saw that two values are used, of type size, and data. In this case, my class doesn't have size, but just stores two values

Comment: `delete` must be consistent with `new`. Where is `new` in your code?

Comment: Numbers are not movable. Constants are not movable (const NP&&).

Answer (score 2):

Since your class does not manage the lifetime/acquisition of any resource follow the rule of zero. Don't write any copy/move ctor/assignment or dtor. They will be implicitly declared.

As a side-note you need to use list initializers in your ctor, especially since your data members are template arguments.